# How to add query parameters to a CacheableJsonResponse's cache?

Tags: routes, caching, 8

I have an API which returns various json, like terms of a vocab, nodes of a type, with specific fields and so on.

Now, in my API I am getting the requested language like so:

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
$lang = $request->query->get('lang', 'en');
```

And load the respective translations of the entities.

Now, how can I add that `$lang` parameter as a cache indicator? So that:

```
/myapi/nodes?lang=en
```

creates another cache than:

```
/myapi/nodes?lang=klingon
```

Also, is that the right way to deliver language specific content in an API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a cache context for the query parameter to the response:

```
$cache_metadata = (new CacheableMetadata())->addCacheContexts(['url.query_args:lang']);
$response->addCacheableDependency($cache_metadata);
```

---

About the second question, when this issue is resolved you can use core REST to deliver translated entities: https://www.drupal.org/node/2135829

Comment: thanks so far!

is the cached output automatically delivered or do I have to take care of that in my controller?

i've read through core rest api but it i didnt find any useful documentary on how to define which fields should be output in which way...

Comment: Also works, at least in rest resource: `$response->getCacheableMetadata()->setCacheContexts(['url.query_args:lang']);`

Comment: What if the query param is multivalue and should cache irrespective of the order of the values? for example ?foo=A,B and ?foo=B,A
How to handle this scenario via CacheContexts?