# How to cache a custom rest resource when using Url::fromUri

Tags: 8

I have a custom rest resource that is returning data using new ResourceResponse():

```
$node = Node::load($nid);
$data = load_data('node', $node);
$response = new ResourceResponse($data);
$response->addCacheableDependency($node);
return $response;
```

This works fine, but if I use the function Url::fromUri into the load_data function I get the error:

```
LogicException: The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering content too early.
```

I can get it to work if I use ModifiedResourceResponse instead of ResourceResponse, but as far as I understand this will disable all caching. As this resource might end up getting intensive I want to make sure it is cached - how can I do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can, try Url::fromUri()->toString()

Comment: Thanks, I am already using Url::fromUri()->toString() in my code

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer:

```
Url::fromUri($var)->toString(TRUE)->getGeneratedUrl();
```

Found here: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/early-rendering-a-lesson-in-debugging-drupal-8

Comment: The error message goes away then but this doesn't cache the response correctly. As the error message has shown there is cache metadata generated by rendering the URL. This is now returned by `toString(TRUE)` in a cacheable object which you need to add to the response `$response->addCacheableDependency();`.

Comment: It might be a good idea to collect the cache metadata in a separate object which you pass to sub functions processing the response data. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232287/how-do-i-correctly-setup-caching-for-my-custom-api-routing